# when doing consecutive awk by pipe, how to keep the original fields to print

Tags: bash, awk

The file is with several fields:

```
string1 string2
```

I would do some process for **string2**, producing some results: **string2 -> result1 result2**:

```
awk '{print $2}' FILE | awk -F. '{DO SOMETHING;print result1,result2}'
```

Now I would output each line as:

```
string1 result1 result2
```

Note that both str1 and str2 include dots (.). In string2, the dots are used as delimiter to do the calculate, and string1's dots should be ignored. So I have to use extract the string2 first, then pipe it to next awk. How to save the string1 in a variable and then pass it to next awk and print it?

I know I can do it in a naive way by outputting results to second file and then combine the string1 and results from separate files, but I would like to learn how to do it in one line.

Thanks for any comment.

Comment: Post some concise, testable sample input and the associated expected output so we can start to help you. Whatever it is you want to do will be trivial in one small awk script.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's response. Finally, I decide to use a script that stores the string1 in a string first, and put the results in another string, and then concatenate them.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that is an absolutely ridiculous approach. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the first `awk` script at all.  Do your processing on second field after splitting with the delimiter and output first field together with the results.  Since you didn't provide real test input/output, here is a mock up.

```
$ echo "a.b.c d.1.2.3" 
  | awk '{split($2,s,"."); 
          result1=s[1]; 
          result2=s[2]"/"s[3]; 
          print $1, result1, result2}'
```

a.b.c d 1/2

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the second awk script can only see the output of the first program, so what you want cannot be done.

The longer answer is that it *can* be done, but only by doing various nasty tricks, such as putting the results into a seperate file, or by execing a new awk for each line, and passing the result in as a -D variable, this can be done by calling 'system("/bin/echo $2 | awk -D"$1" {DO_SOMETHING;…}'. That is not really a nice solution though.

To do something like this, you probably want to upgrade to either Perl or Python, as these give you a much richer scripting environment.

Answer (score 0):

First decide what your `DO SOMETHING` is. When you want to de something that can be done in awk, use awk! When you need to process string2 with some special script/program, you can use a while-construction:

```
while read -r string1 string2; do
   results="$(my_abacadabra ${string2})"
   result1=${result#.*}
   result2=${result%%*.}
   printf "%s %s %s\n" "${string1}" "${result1}" "${string2}"
done < FILE
```

For a large inputfile, take another look to awk first. You want to avoid the while loop, calling `my_abacadabra` for each line will become expensive.